# Paper component not stretching in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The items in the grid are being stretched but the paper component inside is not stretching

```
<Grid
      container
      justifyContent="center"
      direction="row"
      spacing={2}
      alignItems="stretch">
      <Grid item lg={3} md={3}>
        <Paper className={classes.paperClass} elevation={3}>
          <Typography variant="h5">Lorem ipsum dolor</Typography>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic
            obcaecati fugiat, cu
          </Typography>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item lg={3} md={3}>
        <Paper className={classes.paperClass} elevation={3}>
          <Typography variant="h5">Lorem ipsum dolor</Typography>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic
            obcaecati fugiat, cu
          </Typography>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item lg={3} md={3}>
        <Paper className={classes.paperClass} elevation={3}>
          <Typography variant="h5">Lorem ipsum dolor</Typography>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic
            obcaecati fugiat, cur sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic
            obcaecati fugiat, cu
          </Typography>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

I want each paper in grid item to have equal height but the stretch property is not working

Comment: Give the paper elements a `height: 100%` in your css classes.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://mui.com/components/grid/#auto-layout):

> The grid creates visual consistency between layouts while allowing flexibility across a wide variety of designs. Material Design's responsive UI is based on a **12-column grid layout**.

The grid layout is divided into 12 columns. If you want it to stretch 100%, set the grid item prop `xs` to 12 to make it span across all columns:

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: or you can use the shorthand for `xs={12}` which is just `xs`